# just one of the ng-bind-html in page work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind

I write angularjs application and have this block of code but just first html-bind-html works for me

```
<div ng-bind-html='newsTitle'>
  <div ng-bind-html='newsDetail'></div>
</div>
```

When i change the priority like this :

```
<div ng-bind-html='newsDetail'>
  <div ng-bind-html='newsTitle'></div>
</div>
```

It shows newsDetail value.
How many ng-bind-html per page can i declare? why second value doesn't show?

Comment: Are your div tags not closed ? Anyway, I'm not sure you can put a ng-bind-html inside another ng-bind-html.

Comment: they have close tags

Comment: Yes, so look my answer, it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I understand your problem.

```
<div ng-bind-html='newsTitle'> <!-- This will replace the content of the div with $scope.newsTitle -->
  <div ng-bind-html='newsDetail'> <!-- So this won't appear, because it has been removed by  ng-bind-html='newsTitle' -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Look my comments in the code. So if you put newsDetails in the first place, the binded HTML ($scope.newsDetail) will replace the current content aswell.

In a word, **ng-bind-html** replace the current content of your element with the binded HTML you provide. So you shouldn't put HTML in those elements.

You just have to do something like this :

```
<div class="news">
 <div ng-bind-html='newsTitle'></div>
 <div ng-bind-html='newsDetail'></div>
</div>
```

Some docs about ngBindHtml directive : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1):

If it's real copy of your html. Then I suppose that it's problem with structure. Please close your block:

```
<div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and write it like this

```
 <div><span ng-bind-html='newsTitle'></span></div>
 <div><span ng-bind-html='newsDetail'></span></div>
```